# finding cosine using python

Tags: python, factorial, accumulator

I must write a function that computes and returns the cosine of an angle using the first 10 terms of the following series:  `cosx = 1 - (x**2)/2! + (x**4)/4! - (x**6)/6!....`

I can't use the factorial function, but i can use the fact that if the previous denominator was `n!`, the current denominator would be `n!(n+1)(n+2)`. I'm trying to use an accumulator loop, but i'm having a hard time with the fact that it alternates from positive to negative and also having trouble with the denominator.

This is what I have thus far. Any help with the denominator and accumulator loop?

```
def factorial(x):

    if(x == 0): 
        return 1
    return x * factorial(x-1)


def cosine(angle):

    cosx = 1
    sign = -1
    for i in range(2, 20, 2):
        cosx = cosx + (sign*(angle**i))/factorial(i)
        sign = -sign
    return cosx
```

Comment: `^` is not the power operator. You omit the factorial. You omit the sign.

Comment: Cos[x] == Sum[((-1)^k x^(2 k))/(2 k)!], where k is in range (0,10).

Comment: You can use this function for a factorial (squished into one line to fit into this comment): `def factorial(x): return (1 if (x == 0) else x * factorial(x-1))`

Comment: I've made a few changes, but it still isn't giving me the correct return. Is there anything any of you can notice?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3.2

def cos (a):
    d = 1
    c = 1
    for i in range (2, 20, 2):
        d *= i * (i - 1)
        sign = -1 if i % 4 else 1
        print ('adding {} * a ** {} / {}'.format (sign, i, d) )
        c += sign * a ** i / d
        print ('cosine is now {}'.format (c) )
    return c

cos (1.0)
```

Basically `d` (as in Denominator) is your accumulator.

Answer (score 2):

Note: If you are using **Python2.x**, you should use

```
from __future__ import division
```

as the first line of the file

---

One way is to alternate the sign like this

```
def cos(angle):
    sign = -1
    cosx = 1
    for i in range(2,20,2):
         cosx += sign*(x**i)/(i)
         sign = -sign
```

You'll still need to get the factorial part correct

Here is a simpler version that calculates each term based on the previous one.

```
def cos(x):
    res = 0
    term = 1
    for i in range(1, 20, 2):
        res += term
        term *= -x * x/ i /(i + 1)
    return res
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not make a function for factorial? (I added an optional parameter for repetitions):

**EDIT:**

as per a comment, here's a "learning" factorial function that will make sure not to recalculate any values (granted this will only work up to 199!, I'm assuming there will never be more than 99 repetitions with the cos function since it will probably throw an overflow error around 90 already):

```
facts = [0]*200
facts[0] = 1
def factorial(x): 
    if(facts[x] != 0): return facts[x]
    return x * factorial(x-1)

def cos(x, reps=10):
    final_val = 1
    neg = -1
    for n in range(2, reps*2, 2):
        final_val += neg*(x**n)/factorial(n)
        neg *= -1
    return final_val

print cos(3.14/2)
```

Comment: But if you've just calculate 6! isn't is easy (and more efficient) to use that to get to 8! etc?

Comment: You forgot to save the value back into `facts[x]`. What I was meaning was more like the alternate way I added to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

For calculating series, use the power of list comprehensions.

```
In [1]: a = range(1,11)

In [2]: a
Out[2]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

The `mul` function multiplies the elements of the list it is given:

```
In [3]: def mul(r):
   ...:     rv = 1
   ...:     for j in r:
   ...:         rv *= j
   ...:     return rv
   ...:
```

Now you can generate the factorials:

```
In [7]: b = [mul(a[:i]) for i in a]

In [8]: b
Out[8]: [1, 2, 6, 24, 120, 720, 5040, 40320, 362880, 3628800]
```

To pick the right elements from the lists;

```
In [10]: a[1::2]
Out[10]: [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]

In [11]: b[1::2]
Out[11]: [2, 24, 720, 40320, 3628800]
```

To generate the plusses and minuses:

```
In [12]: [(-1)**k for k in a[:5]]
Out[12]: [-1, 1, -1, 1, -1]
```

Combine all the elements;

```
In [14]: data = zip(a[1::2], b[1::2], [(-1)**k for k in a[:5]])
```

Then do the calculation for a certain `x`;

```
In [21]: x = 12

In [22]: sum([s*x**t/float(b) for t, b, s in data])
Out[22]: -9753.737142857142
```

Comment: Just as @gnibbler said^, if you calculate 6! and then 8! wouldn't it be more efficient to utilize the fact that you've already done the math? (even more so if you go the other way, from 8 to 6)

Comment: @Josh The comprehension to generate `b` runs in 10.7 µs on my machine. Why should I worry about efficiency in this case?